# Get unique options in a row, of specific column using pandas

Tags: python, csv, pandas, rows

I have a dataset that looks something like this:

```
ID  Result1 Result2
1   Yes     Pos
2   No      Neg
3   No      Pos
4   Yes     Neg
5   Yes     Neg
6   No      Pos
```

My main goal is split the dataset (which is much larger than this) into subsets based on certain criteria. I want to be able to run this splitting process by selecting the column that contains the deciding criteria, and then selecting the option to perform the splitting process.

For example:

```
Please enter column to segment by:
-Result2

Please enter the criteria in [Results2] to segment by:
-Pos
```

Then it should output the same dataset, but only containing the data for all fields corresponding to "Pos" results in the Results2 column.

So far I can select the column with this code:

```
import pandas as pd
# Read in the data from the csv
df = pd.read_csv("filename.csv",sep = ";")

# Get the column headers
headers = list(df.columns.values)

# Display the header options fo user
for k in range(0,len(headers)):
    print k,headers[k]


# Get the column to sort the file by
header_idx = int(raw_input("\nPlease choose the header to segment by: (0,1,2 etc) \n"))
```

Now I want to list all the available options in the selected column to the user and call the segmentation function (which is a bridge I still need to cross).

Comment: Maybe you can use `print df.ix[:, header_idx]`

Comment: why do you read the columns and then assign it back? `headers = list(df.columns.values)

df.columns = headers` this is redundant

Comment: @EdChum Yeah I was trying to work backwards. Like when you read in a csv with read_csv() you can set the names of the headers with read_csv(csv_file, headers = ["ID","Result1","Result2"]).

Then you can access those columns with df.Result1. 

So I was trying to set the columns after reading it in. Didnt work though

Comment: @jezrael That does print all the entries of that row, but considering that my rows are about 500 entries long, thats not really an option to print it out each time I want to segment

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I follow, but is this what you are looking to do?

```
col = raw_input('Please enter column to segment by: ')
val = raw_input('Please enter the criteria in to segment by: ')
df2 = df[df.loc[:,col]==val]
print df2
```

Comment: Yeah thats part of it, but I would ideally like to show the user which options are available to choose as criteria, because there are about 40+ fields and all of them have different positives and negatives. 
Does that make sense?

Comment: You could `print df[col].tolist()` for the user, or `print [(i,c) for i,c in enumerate(df[col].tolist())]` if you want numbers with the names.  Is that what you mean?